# MongoDB get the data collection by querying the Nth element dynamically

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a dynamic stack of ticket's status. where each ticket can be at status "**In Process**" and have different "**this.statusStack.currentStatus**" value.

The next code (that doesn't work) tries to explain what I'm trying to do

```
var tickets = Tickets.find({
  driverAsigned: Meteor.userId(),
  'statusStack.stack.(this.statusStack.currentStatus).name': "In Process"
});
```

*****NEW DATA******

what I mean with "**this.statusStack.currentStatus**" is an inner document value not as a variable of my code.

Here is the structure of a ticket

```
{
......
"statusStack" : {
    "stack" : [
        {
            "sortable" : false,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 0,
            "name" : "Draft",
            "customName" : "Draft",
            "description" : "When the ticket has been created",
            "color" : "#4d4d4d"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : false,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 1,
            "name" : "New",
            "customName" : "New",
            "description" : "When the ticket info has been updated",
            "color" : "#f4f93e"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : true,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 2,
            "name" : "Assigned",
            "customName" : "Assigned",
            "description" : "When the ticket info has been asigned to a driver",
            "color" : "#3e89f9"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : true,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 3,
            "name" : "In Process",
            "customName" : "In Process",
            "description" : "When the ticket has been created",
            "color" : "#f0883c"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : true,
            "removable" : true,
            "order" : 4,
            "name" : "Frodo",
            "customName" : "Blank",
            "description" : "New Blank Status",
            "color" : "#4d4d4d"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : true,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 5,
            "name" : "Resolved",
            "customName" : "Resolved",
            "description" : "When the Driver has resolved the Ticket",
            "color" : "#42f93e"
        },
        {
            "sortable" : false,
            "removable" : false,
            "order" : 6,
            "name" : "Closed",
            "customName" : "Closed",
            "description" : "When the Admin has been closed the Ticket",
            "color" : "#217b1f"
        }
    ],
    "currentStatus" : 5
},
......
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample document for Tickets collection and more clarification that what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo Code:

1. Get array element Position First.

   pos = statusStack.currentStatus
2. Then you can use that pos (int)variable to build query document

   var query = tojson('{"statusStack.stack.'+pos'+'.name": "In Process"}');

Use that query document inside find.

Comment: What I'm trying is to avoid to query all those Tickets that I don't need.

If I do as you said I would retrieve all tickets then iterate to get only the ones I want

`var tickets = Tickets.find({ driverAsigned: Meteor.userId()});`

`tickets.forEach(function(ticket) {
       if(ticket.statusStack.stack[ticket.statusStack.currentStatus].name === "In Process"){
//Do what I want
}
});`

Which I consider a little bit heavy

Comment: I Agree... Look into aggregation framework and see if you find any way using that. Aggregation framework provides so many extra stuff that we can use.